# CSS how to make color:orange when a DOM has .red and .yellow at the same time?

Tags: css, sass

for example I have a div like :

```
<div class="red yellow"><div>
```

and my css:

```
.red{background-color:red;}
.yellow{background-color:yellow;}
```

and how can I make my div's background-color becomes to orange when it has .red and .yellow class at the same time? I think the similar way is like:

```
.red .yellow{background-color:orange;}
```

I know it's not the right way , but how can I archive my requirement?

Comment: Just add a custom class with background-color:orange; the browser will read the css in the order it is written

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between two class names. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way. There shouldn't be a space between two class names.

```
.red.yellow { background-color:orange; }
```

See this snippet.

```css
.red { background-color:red; }
.yellow { background-color:yellow; }
.red.yellow { background-color:orange; }
```

```html
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="red yellow">Orange</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="red yellow"><div>
```

CSS

```
div{height:100px;} /* I added dummy height for div just to show output */

.red { background-color:red; }
.yellow { background-color:yellow; }
.red.yellow{background-color:orange;}
```

OUTPUT

[image]